# How to determine the matplotlib legend?

Tags: matplotlib, legend

I have 3 lists to plot as curves. But every time I run the same plt lines, even with the `ax.legend(loc='lower right', handles=[line1, line2, line3])`, these 3 lists jumps randomly in the legend like below. Is it possible to fix their sequences and the colors for the legend as well as the curves in the plot?

[image]

[image]

EDIT:
My code is as below:

```
def plot_with_fixed_list(n, **kwargs):
    np.random.seed(0)
    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
    my_handles = []
    for key, values in kwargs.items():
        value_name = key
        temp, = ax1.plot(np.arange(1, n+ 1, 1).tolist(), values, label=value_name)
        my_handles.append(temp)

    ax1.legend(loc='lower right', handles=my_handles)
    ax1.grid(True, which='both')
    plt.show()

plot_with_fixed_list(300, FA_Hybrid=fa, BP=bp, Ssym_Hybrid=ssym)
```

Comment: Since matplotlib does not have a `randomlegendgenerator()` function, something in the code before the plotting changes the order of the plotted lists. Please provide a minimal, complete, and reproducible example of your problem.

Comment: The order in the default legend, is the same order in which the curves were added to the plot. If the curves are created with seaborn, setting the `hue_order=` parameter creates more consistency.

Comment: Do you mean `plot_with_fixed_list(np.arange(274), FA_Hybrid=fa, BP=bp, Ssym_Hybrid=ssym)`? It would not make sense to plot them against an integer (and you would get an error message, unless the data of length 1, in which case you would return an empty plot). Anyhow, this code does not reproduce the problem because they are plotted in the order provided - `FA, BP, SSYM` - and this is always the order of the legend.

Comment: Hi @Mr.T, thank you for your reply. I made a mistake when trying to provide the minimum reproducible code. Actually, I found that this non-determinism bug resides in python==3.5, matplotlib==3.0.0. After updating to the matplotlib==3.3.2, the order won't be messed anymore.

Comment: Well, you are encouraged to [write and accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This nondeterminism bug resides with python==3.5, matplotlib==3.0.0. After I updated to python==3.6, matplotlib==3.3.2, problem solved.